# Three.js setting environment map to model overwrite its own texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to set environment map to a OBJ model, but it has changed too much!
in usual view, it look like it
[image: a normal]
but when i set env map , it turned
[image]
like it turned jade to iron !!!
code is inspired by office demo

```js
  new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(
          imageUrlList,
          (cubeTexture) => {
            console.log('cubeTexture 222', cubeTexture)
            scene.environment = cubeTexture
            // scene.background = cubeTexture
            model.traverse(function (item) {
              if (item.isMesh) {
                item.material.envMap = cubeTexture
              }
            })
            console.log('model', model)
          }
```

so can somebody help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set material.reflectivity to 0.2 because OBJ model use MeshPhongMaterial default, and it worked! –